# Redis.dll not found for php8.2

Tags: php-extension, phpredis

I am experiencing difficulties starting Redis 5.3.7 with PHP 8.2 on my Windows machine. When I attempt to start it, a dialog box displays with the message:

> "The procedure entry point _zend_get_parameters_array_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\Program Files\php\ext\php_redis.dll"

I have included a screenshot of the error below:

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here the way I solve the problem

DLL is Officially released in PHP packages site
you can find the package here https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.3.7/windows

**My Old Solution:**

go to this page https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/actions/runs/5916330188#artifacts, extensions are listed there.

working for me on xampp, php8.2.1 and redis 3.2.100 on windows 11

Comment: For any newer version you can do this: Go to [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/commits/) on GitHub → select desired branch (e.g. `releases/6.0.2`) → click on the green "✔" next to commit message → click on "Details" next to any `ci.yml` job → click on "Summary" in the left sidebar → scroll down to the "Artifacts" section → download desired version

Answer (score 5):

How to compile a PHP extension like Redis, under Windows. Since nobody really explains that.

Run commands under the old Windows shell, e.g. `cmd.exe`

You will need the 2019 version of the Microsoft C/C++ compiler, so the linker is compatible with the downloadable PHP for Windows. `winget` can found as "[App Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4NNS1)" in the Windows Store.

```
winget install --id Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools
```

In the Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 'modify' the install under the 'Individual components' tab, and select:

- C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.29-16.11)
- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools

Download PHP for Windows, also download and unzip the 'Development package (SDK to develop PHP extensions)' and probable also the 'Debug Pack'. In the 'Development package' there is a folder, you need to unzip the contents of that folder to the folder where you have `php.exe`. https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.2

Git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis inside the folder where you have `php.exe`.

```
winget install --id Git.Git
git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
# or:
winget install --id Git.Git
winget install --id GitHub.cli
gh repo clone phpredis/phpredis
```

You might want to switch away from the main `develop` branch:

```
git tag # find the latest non-RC version, currently that is 5.3.7
git checkout 5.3.7
```

In a command shell `cmd.exe` inside the directory where you have `php.exe`.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.29
cd phpredis 
..\phpize.bat
.\configure.bat --enable-redis --with-prefix=%cd%\..
```

Check that in the Makefile `PHP_PREFIX` and `PHP_SRC_DIR` point to the directory holding php.exe and the phpredis source code, e.g.

- `PHP_SRC_DIR ="C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.2.7-Win32-vs16-x64\phpredis"`
- `PHP_PREFIX="C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.2.7-Win32-vs16-x64\"`

Then build with:

```
nmake clean
nmake
copy x64\Release_TS\php_redis.dll ..\ext\
```

In the php.ini:

```
extension=php_redis.dll
```

Then run `php -m` to see redis listed.