# Why is the Redis extension not working with PHP 8.2?

Tags: php, redis, xampp, pecl

I am using the latest stable version of PHP 8.2.4 with XAMPP on Windows 11 x64. I want to install the Redis extension in the PHP ext folder. However, after installing the DLL file and registering it in the php.ini file, the Redis installation still does not appear on the phpinfo page. Additionally, it throws a warning on the command line while running php -v. In PECL site the latest supported PHP version is 8.1. Does it mean that currently there is no way to use redis with PHP 8.2.4?

I need help on how to install Redis in Xampp having PHP 8.2.4.

First of all I downloaded the DLL file for both TS and NTS from the PECL for x64 that is compatible with my machine. Although the latest version they provde is for PHP 8.1 not PHP 8.2.

[image]

Then I added the DLL file from the source file to the php/ext folder.

[image]

Then I registered this DLL file into the php.ini config file.

[image]

Then I checked the installation through the phpinfo(). but there was no section of Redis. Additionally when I run php -v in CLI, it gives warning as follows.

[image]

Note: I have tried both Thread safe and Non Thread safe DLL for this matter. Both are not working.

Comment: I would use docker. So you can have multiple instances of any version you like and have *nix under the hood which is more flexible with web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76496489/15166658.

It appears that there is a Redis DLL available for PHP 8.2:

[image: php_redis.dll]

Furthermore, it has been reported to work well with PHP 8.2.1 and Redis 3.2.100 on Windows 11.

UPDATE:

download link: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/actions/runs/4930167168#artifacts

UPDATE:

[image: phpinfo output]

test with simple code:
[image: execute in simple code]

Comment: If you find that another answer on stackoverflow solves the problem, you would normally mark it as a duplicate and flag to be closed (if you can - leave a comment if you can't vote to close)

Comment: Unfortunately, the given DLL doesn't work for PHP 8.2.4

Comment: @NigelRen, certainly, but unfortunately, I am unable to leave a comment on the main article due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: @Vivek, hello! double-check using the correct DLL (redis-8.2-x64-ts.zip). I have tested it with XAMPP (PHP 8.2.4).

Comment: @pickuse, Yes it is working with "TS". Initially, I tried only with "NTS" because the DLL for older versions was only supported for NTS, not TS. Thanks for the solution. Appreciated.